# Calculator exception handling, why does this example work but mine does not?

Tags: python, exception, calculator

For a bit of python practice, I decided to work on a calculator tutorial.  It was very basic, so I decided to give it exception handling in the event a user enters in garbage.  While proper use of the program still works, punching in crap still causes it to crash, and entering 
Here is my code:

```
loop = 1

choice = 0

while loop == 1:
    #print out the options you have
    print "Welcome to calculator.py"

    print "your options are:"

    print " "
    print "1) Addition"
    print "2) Subtraction"

    print "3) Multiplication"

    print "4) Division"
    print "5) Quit calculator.py"
    print " "

    choice = input("choose your option: ")
    try:
        if choice == 1:
            add1 = input("add this: ")
            add2= input("to this: ")
            print add1, "+", add2, "=", add1+ add2
        elif choice == 2:
            sub1 = input("Subtract this ")
            sub2 = input("from this")
            print sub1, "-", sub2, "=", sub1 - sub2
        elif choice == 3:
            mul1 = input("Multiply this: ")
            mul2 = input("with this: ")
            print mul1, "x", mul2, "=", mul1 * mul2
        elif choice == 4:
            div1 = input("Divide this: ")
            div2 = input("by this: ")
            if div2 == 0:
                print "Error! Cannot divide by zero!  You'll destroy the universe! ;)"
            else:

                print div1, "/", div2, "=", div1 * div2
        elif choice == 5:
            loop = 0
        else:
            print "%d is not valid input. Please enter 1, 2 ,3 ,4 or 5." % choice

    except ValueError:
        print "%r is not valid input.  Please enter 1, 2, 3, 4 or 5." % choice
    print "Thank you for using calculator.py!"
```

Now while I found an useable answer here: [Error Handling Variables in a calculator program, Error handling numbers are fine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5228641/error-handling-variables-in-a-calculator-program-error-handling-numbers-are-fin)

I was wondering why my code didn't work.  Does python want the exception handling in a function?  That's the vibe I'm getting from it.

Comment: What is the traceback you get?

Comment: Is there a reason you multiply the two inputs, when the user wants to divide them?

Comment: @kratenko That was a bug. thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @MartijnPieters the trace back is
    choose your option: ad
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "practice.py", line 21, in <module>
    choice = input("choose your option: ")
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'ad' is not defined

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Python 2 (which is what you are using) `input` evaluates as Python code whatever the user enters.  Because of this `input` can raise many different exceptions, but rarely a `ValueError`.

Better would be to accept your input with the `raw_input` which returns a string, and then cast to the expected type.  If the input is invalid it will then raise a `ValueError`:

```
>>> x = int(raw_input("enter something: "))
enter something: sdjf
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'sdjf'
```

Note:  In Python 3 `input` assumes the semantics of Python 2's `raw_input` and `raw_input` goes away.

Comment: Or a NameError (enter 'abcde'), or a ZeroDivisionError (enter '1/0'), or whatever you can think of.

Answer (score 2):

You're catching `ValueError`, which is the wrong thing to catch.

Take a look how `input()` works:

```
>>> print input.__doc__
input([prompt]) -> value

Equivalent to eval(raw_input(prompt)).
```

So what it's doing is evaluating what you type in at that point, in the same way it evaluates anything you type in an interactive Python session. For example, I get a `NameError` if I try to enter `garbagestring` at a prompt, for the same reason I get a `NameError` if I try to enter `garbagestring` at the interactive prompt:

```
>>> garbagestring
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'garbagestring' is not defined
```

The correct way to do this is to use `raw_input()` in place of `input()`, then convert the string that returns into an integer:

```
>>> raw_input('Prompt: ')
Prompt: garbagestring
'garbagestring'
>>> int(raw_input('Prompt: '))
Prompt: garbagestring
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'garbagestring'
>>> int(raw_input('Prompt: '))
Prompt: 45
45
```

This will catch the error as you use it.

Note in general you should avoid doing anything that looks vaguely like an `eval()`. Generally you can achieve anything you need to without it, and `eval()` is potentially a security risk if using a string you don't trust. For example, if I add `import os` (a pretty damn common import) at the top of your script, I can do this:

```
Multiply this: os.listdir('/')
with this: 0
['bin', 'cygdrive', 'dev', 'etc', 'home', 'lib', 'tmp', 'usr', 'var', 'proc'] x 0 = []
Thank you for using calculator.py!
```

I could just as easily read files, delete vital folders, etc etc.

Answer (score 0):

`input` does an `eval()` on user's input, `input` basically does a `eval(raw_input(prompt))`

So if you input `loop`, it won't fail, it actually will set `choice` to `1`.

If you input `a`, it will eval and raise a `NameError` exception.

If you input `1 + 1` it will substract.

I hope you get the idea.